# When is the next release?

Tags: version-11.3

I've been looking into buying a student version of Mathematica but saw the latest release was almost a year ago. The previous release cycle looked like it was every several months or so. I run Ubuntu 18.04, which doesn't have formal support for Mathematica 11.3, but seems to run fine for me. I was wondering if anyone knows when the next release might be? I would hate to buy a license and then a new version come out not too long after so I'd have to upgrade to get proper support on my computer.

Comment: I got an e-mail in December from Wolfram, Inc. stating that new users and those upgrading to 11.3 would receive version 12 for free.  But I don't see such a statement at the Wolfram online store.

Comment: That's good to know @JimB, thanks for the info!

Comment: In a webinar (about 10-dec) someone said the release was expected late January, but I think things might very well be very different already.

Comment: The latest Live CEOing video starts out with Stephen talking about being at "the very tail end of version 12 stuff" so we can assume it'll be relatively soon.

Comment: IIRC if you buy a version and then they release a new one "shortly after" they'll upgrade you for free. I don't know the cutoff though.

Comment: This is something you really must ask Wolfram, not other users.

Comment: Interesting: That problem might be reformulated as a problem of stochastic optimal control. Optimal home version buying strategy as opposed to a SaaS-scheme. :)

Comment: I've actually chatted with Wolfram support and didn't get a ton of help. They just said releases are only known by the development team and that if I purchased Mathematica now, I'd have to pay the upgrade fee when a new version came out. That's a slightly different story than I've heard here, but at the same time understandable because Wolfram is a business and doesn't want to be giving that kind of information out to the public. I guess that's why I came here to ask the question.

Comment: I think the trick is that upgrades depends on wether you take the option "Premier Service" or not.

Comment: April 16 according to [this](https://www.facebook.com/wolframresearch/posts/10156493527323795?comment_id=10156493781873795&reply_comment_id=10156493914603795)

Comment: @JimB I'm not seeing anyway to upgrade to version 12 for free. Have you seen anything?

Comment: Yes. I’ve already downloaded it. The email stating that I could download it came a couple hours later.

Comment: @JimB what would you suggest if one didn't get that email but meets the criterion you mentioned above?

Comment: Either call customer service or wait s few days.  It takes a while before all of the emails go out.